# Java Swing dependent field validation

Tags: java, swing, validation

During a focus transfer, is there a way to validate dependent fields such that a focus transfer among JComponents (a, b, c) is not vetoed but a focus transfer to some external element (say, d) is vetoed?

The most natural place to do such a thing seems to be in `InputVerifier.shouldYieldFocus()`; however, I don't see a way to obtain the (next) focus target at that time.

Comment: I suspect that this somehow violates some Java Focus Subsystem principle or else there would be an obvious (if not simple) way to accomplish this.

Comment: for sooner/better help you have to edit your post with runnable example that shows your issues, http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thanks, if I can find a way to reduce the application I'm working on into a simple example, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported by the InputVerifier mechanism. And probably shouldn't at that level of granularity because it might lead to giving focus to d with invalid data in a.

Assume an InputVerifier which does know the opposite component (that is the potential next focusOwner) and its data is invalid

- in shouldYieldFocus it tests the opposite

  - for b it allows the transfer
- transferred focus to b
- transfer focus to d (allowed)

(same overall effect with Rob's suggestion, btw, except that the a's InputVerifier is never run)

On the whole, the built-in validation support isn't very strong - lots of work left for the developer. Some things you would need to do

- can use InputVerifiers on the per-component level to actually do the validation, shouldYield returns true always
- have some "InputVerifierController" which checks whether the focus is going "to the outside"
- if going "outside" with any invalid data anywhere "inside" prevent the transfer

Using a framework like f.i. JGoodies Validation might be easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'm mostly having difficulty because I'm using my own custom InputVerifier but I don't seem to have visibility to the opposite component.  Your second recommendation (using some "InputVerifierController") seems promising; I'll look into what Swing implements in terms of a controller for calling InputVerifier to validate a focus transfer.

Answer (score 2):

For the dependent components you should be able to use:

```
component.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget( false );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the need to verify the input of what the user typed into the field as this could trigger other actions.